# How to disable Sencha Touch 2 page transition animations?

Tags: javascript, animation, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I searched all around for it but couldn't find a solution which would turn off sliding (or any animation for that matter) animation on page transition. I have simple application with 4 views which just displays a bunch of data. I am testing performance of my application on various devices and thought turning off animations would be one of the test cases to follow.

I tried several ways, such as: (caution: these are all the solutions I found on the internet, some of them might not make sense. I am still learning the framework :)

**Trial I:** (in launch function)

```
Ext.override(Ext.Window, {
            animShow: function(){
                this.afterShow();
            },
            animHide: function(){
                this.el.hide();
                this.afterHide();
            }
        });
```

**Trial II:** (in launch function, replacing Trial I)

```
Ext.Anim.override({
            disableAnimations:true
        });
```

**Trial III:** (inside my view class)

```
config: {
        showAnimation: false,
        hideAnimation: false,
        navigationBar: {
            hidden   : false,
            animation: false
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'logincard',
                flex : 1
            }
        ]
    }
```

However, I could turn off animation in navigation bar using: (in my view class as well)

```
navigationBar: {
                hidden   : false,
                animation: false
            }
```

So is there someway of totally disabling the page transition animation in Sencha Touch 2.2.1?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you use Navigation view as the parent view? Because TabPanel or NavigationView generally add animation but not default card layout.

Comment: I used navigation view on Main whose controller then `push`es other views. I do not have a global main parent. They are just separate individual views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got it working. I guess I didn't have adequate information on my question. I was using `Navigation View` which would consequently `push` other views via controllers.

All I had to do was put the following layout configuration inside `config` of my `Main` view which extends `Navigation View`.

```
    layout: {
            type: 'card',
            animation: false
    }
```

This would disable the animation on screen transition. Additionally, you can override  `duration`, `type`, etc of the animation using the following configuration:

```
layout: {
    type: 'card',
    animation: {
        duration: 300,
        easing: 'ease-out',
        type: 'slide',
        direction: 'left'
    }
}
```

This is the default configuration for animation for `Navigation View`. I found help from [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?180663-Disable-transition-animations-in-Ext.navigation.View).

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem after disabling the animation I got errors like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null
```

The solution is a super-fast animation:

```
animation: {
    duration: 1,
    //easing: 'ease-out',
    type: 'fade'
    //direction: 'left'
}
```